# Regex in clojure 1.7

Tags: regex, parsing, clojure

I am quite the nob with reg ex and it seems clear they are several flavours of regex.

I am working with clojure and an online tool http://regexr.com/.

I have come across several examples on stackoverflow and else where but they dont seem to always work.
Below is what i have tried to achieve but the output is wrong

```
\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d
```

Here are sample inputs string

> I used to have 1,956,827.19 USD I once spent 987.99 USD in one days before my bank put a cap on 900 and 2 years later i have a balance of 1,200.8 USD.

So after parsing it i expect a list `("1,956,827.19" "987.99" "900" "2" "1,200.8")` so I expect 5 elements.

I am using the following expression

```
  (re-seq 
     (re-pattern Regex my-sentence))
```

Any advise i will be most grateful.

Comment: You're describing your desired output, but not your actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you'd look at your *actual* output and how it differs.

Running

```
(map first (re-seq #"\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d"
                   "I used to have 1,956,827.19 USD I once spent 987.99 USD in one days before my bank put a cap on 900 and 2 years later i have a balance of 1,200.8 USD.")
```

...yields as output...

```
("1,956,827.19" "987.99" "900" "2" "1,200" "8")
```

Obviously, the only part of this that is wrong is the content after the decimal point matching separately. This is happening because you're forcing `\.\d\d` -- two digits after the decimal point -- but in your test string there's only one.

```
#"\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?"
```

...lacks this problem.

Nothing specific to Clojure here -- you'd have the same issue with any PCRE-derived regex syntax and test data.

Comment: Thanks i slightly altered it to \d{1,}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?

I really appreciate it

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `\d(?:[\d,.]*\d)?`? Limiting yourself to groups of digits of specific sizes is potentially prone to causing a significant number of false negatives.